# Why does my Dell display have an USB cable hanging from it?

Tags: usb, display

I have a Dell display at work which by default connects to the PC I use not just via a HDMI, but an USB cable as well. Unplugging or plugging it back makes no noticeable difference (e.g. it doesn't carry sound or anything like that). What's its purpose?

Comment: Does the monitor have USB ports?

Comment: What model? Most likely your monitor comes with a build in USB hub. Are there any USB ports on it?

Comment: Yup, that was it, thanks! I was actually thinking about that, but since I haven't seen USB ports in the front (which would make a lot more sense in my opinion, than ports hidden in the hard-to-access back), I didn't think that would be the case.

Comment: typically it lets you have one cable to the computer, and let you plug your mouse/keyboard into the monitor, which makes it easier to move the computer under the desk or such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you'll have USB ports on the monitor. If so, then the USB is used to allow the USB ports on the back of the monitor work (to be detected by the computer).